# How to display items of a certain category in OpenCart 2?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I need to display items of a certain category on homepage in OpenCart 2. How can I do that? 
My code from controller:

```
   $products_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();
   $data['products'] = $products_info;
```

Comment: Why you are getting $this->request->get['product_id'] , this should be $this->request->get['category_id'], because you are getting products of a certain category.

Comment: add this in your controller,  $products_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getCatProducts(your category id); and also in your model create getCatProducts($catid) function and write your own query and pass category id to it, this will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've first loaded the model you're calling:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

All you need to do is define an array of settings to pass to `getProducts()`.  In this case you can get away with only sending the category ID you want to get products for:

```
$filter_data = array(
    'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
);
```

Then call the function as you did:

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
```

Then iterate over the products just as if you were in a category viewto pass data to the view:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result['image']) {
        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));
    } else {
        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));
    }

    if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
        $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
    } else {
        $price = false;
    }

    if ((float)$result['special']) {
        $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
    } else {
        $special = false;
    }

    if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
        $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price']);
    } else {
        $tax = false;
    }

    if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
        $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
    } else {
        $rating = false;
    }

    $data['products'][] = array(
        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
        'thumb'       => $image,
        'name'        => $result['name'],
        'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
        'price'       => $price,
        'special'     => $special,
        'tax'         => $tax,
        'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
        'rating'      => $result['rating'],
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
    );
}
```

Now you have an array of products to display however you'd like in your tpl.